# MySQL Insert Select Doesn't Enforce NOT NULL Constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, notnull, insert-select

I'm having an issue with MySQL 5.6 InnoDb ignoring a NOT NULL foreign key when running an `INSERT INTO xxx (col) SELECT ...`. The constraint is enforced properly when running insert statements in other formats. Foreign key checks are enabled, and `sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Parent
(
    id BIGINT(18) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dummy VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT 'Test parent table';

CREATE TABLE Test_Child
(
    id BIGINT(18) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fid BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY Fk_Test_Parent_01(fid) REFERENCES Test_Parent(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT 'Test child table';

INSERT INTO Test_Parent(dummy)
VALUES ('test');

## Here's where the FK constraint should be enforced but isn't ##
INSERT INTO Test_Child(fid)
SELECT id
    FROM Test_Parent
WHERE dummy = 'missing value';

1 row affected in 5ms

## Running an insert with a different format, the constraint is enforced ##
INSERT INTO Test_Child(fid)
VALUES (null);
Column 'fid' cannot be null

## Running this format, the foreign key is also enforced ##
INSERT INTO Test_Child(id, fid)
VALUES (123, (SELECT id FROM Test_Parent WHERE dummy = 'missing value'));
Column 'fid' cannot be null
```

I don't understand why MySQL will enforce the foreign key for 2 out of the 3 insert statements. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if you're seeing a misreported "1 row affected" because that `INSERT...SELECT` is not actually resulting in any row insert because the `WHERE` clause doesn't match.  If I `SELECT *` from both tables, I see no rows in `Test_Child`...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7413e0/1

Comment: That is, unless your real data and use case differs significantly from the test set you setup for us.

Comment: That's right - it reports 1 row as being inserted, but nothing has actually been inserted into the table. I would expect the `NOT NULL`  constraint to be enforced in this scenario. Instead, it's as if the exception is swallowed.

Comment: But in your real test data, does the `WHERE dummy = 'missing value'` actually return a row? If not, it will always result in zero rows inserted and therefore no FK violation. But your MySQL version may have a bug in the affected rows output.  I tried it on 5.7 and 5.6.35, but both mine reported zero rows inserted rather than 1.

Comment: You're correct. I was running the SQL queries inside IntelliJ and it reported the result `1 row affected in 5ms`. I ran the same queries from the MySQL command line, and received `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`. The question remains, why does inserting as select in this format not raise the NOT NULL constraint violation, whereas in other formats it does?

Comment: Because it never even attempts an insert if there's no row from the `SELECT`.  It's different from your 3rd example, where the literal `123` forces a row insert along with a `NULL` returned from the subselect. If you tried something like `INSERT INTO Test_Child (fid) SELECT NULL FROM Test_Parent` where the select does return a row with a `NULL` value, you should get a FK violation.

Comment: Anyway, I'll summarize this as a proper answer below.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Thanks for your help @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A misleading `1 row affected in 5ms` message from your client may be the source of confusion here.  In the comment thread you mentioned IntelliJ was reporting that message, but I ran your well-defined test tables in both MySQL 5.6.35 and 5.7.16-ubuntu and in both versions the statement in question reported 0 affected rows:

```
mysql > INSERT INTO Test_Child(fid)
    -> SELECT id
    ->     FROM Test_Parent
    -> WHERE dummy = 'missing value';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So looking past the misleading affected rows message, what's really happening here is that the `SELECT` portion of your `INSERT...SELECT` statement matches no rows, and therefore MySQL does not make an attempt at inserting any row.  There was therefore no foreign key constraint violation.

The format of the `INSERT INTO...SELECT` differs a little from your later example:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Child(id, fid)
VALUES (123, (SELECT id FROM Test_Parent WHERE dummy = 'missing value'));
```

...because in this case, the numeric literal `123` forces one row to be inserted, and it is paired with a `null` value returned from the subselect.  So that `null` is attempted to insert and causes a constraint violation.

If you force the `INSERT...SELECT` to return a row with a null value, you can make fail due to a constraint violation:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Child (fid)
-- Return a literal NULL row...
SELECT NULL as id FROM Test_Parent
-- Column fid cannot be null
```